# 301 Redirect for URL's with Query string

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I want to do a 301 redirect for all urls with a query string to the base url (without the query string).

For example:

1. http://www.mysite.com/directory/abcbd.html?q1=23&q2=89
   should be redirected to
   http://www.mysite.com/directory/abcbd.html

   1. http://www.mysite.com/directorynew/file3.html?q1=213&q2=389&q3=ttim
      should be redirected to
      http://www.mysite.com/directorynew/file3.html

As shown in the above examples "q1=" will ALWAYS appear in the beginning in the urls in question. The next set of urls could vary. So is there something like: RewriteCond %{query_string} "q1=.*" - not good at these things!

What entries do I need to enter in the .htaccess file?

Thanks,
Sameer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have done it with this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?.*  $1  [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I got it done using the wp_redirect plugin.

source: /(.*)/(.*).html(.*)\?dontneedthisstring=(.*)
target: /$1/$2.html

This cleans it up.

Here "dontneedthisstring" was the uniq string i was trying to get rid of.